# ElasticBeanStalk Nodejs/Angular Deployment issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

While deploying Angular code on Elasticbeanstalk through Codepipeline on AWS, Got below error.

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/app/staging/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.225-169.362.amzn2.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v14.16.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/var/app/staging/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /var/app/staging/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-25T17_15_54_603Z-debug.log

Any Help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with AWS but since this is a app service, you shouldn't need to grant any permissions (unlike in virtual machine). I think the problem is that your code is trying to create a directory to certain location which is not permitted by AWS.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Engineer